# Ruby Superclass creates a Stack error

Tags: ruby, stack-overflow, superclass

The program below is an attempt to take in an American president, and French President's age, and name. The catch is that the French president says "bein sur" afterward calling his name, age and citizenship (not my idea). I'm having trouble with the French president's catchphrase. Here's my code

```
class President
  attr_accessor :name, :age

  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name 
    @age = age
  end 

end

class FrancePresident < President
  def self.citizenship
    "La France"
  end 

  def initialize(name, age)
    super(name, age)
  end

 def catchphrase
    "bien sur"
  end

   def name
    "#{name}, #{catchphrase}"
   end 

   def age
    "#{age}, #{catchphrase}"
   end 

   def citizenship
     "#{self.class.citizenship}, #{catchphrase}"
   end
end

class UnitedStatesPresident < President
  def self.citizenship
    "The Unites States of America"
  end
end
```

I think I'm referring to the superclass incorrectly because I'm receiving the stack error below.

```
SystemStackError
stack level too deep
exercise.rb:29
```

I'm new to Ruby, so any insight will be helpful.

Comment: This is kind of a mess from an Object-Oriented design perspective as what you're doing here is pushing a lot of display logic into your classes, you should be thinking in terms of [model-view-presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–presenter) where this is the model and another class handles assembling text with the correct phrasing.

Comment: This MVP article seems to be over my head at my current skill level as I only know Ruby and a little SML. Hopefully I'll visit this again someday soon with a little more expertise.

Comment: @ tadman: I'm starting to look at MVP now in my full stack course. Do you know of any good resources I can check out?

Comment: From an academic perspective, the [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) book is a great place to start. For a more pragmatic, applied approach, the OS X/iOS API rigorously applies these principles. There's a number of books like [Cocoa Design Patterns](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/cocoa-design-patterns/9780321591210/) that explains how these work.

Answer (score 3):

Your `name` function generates infinite recursion, because it calls itself:

```
def name
    "#{name}, #{catchphrase}" # <-- here, name calls this very function again and again
end
```

Same goes for `age`. They should call the instance variables, `@name` and `@age`, respectively:

```
def name
    "#{@name}, #{catchphrase}"
end 

def age
    "#{@age}, #{catchphrase}"
end
```

#### Edit

It's probably better still to use `super` instead of the instance variables, because it makes it clear that you are using the functionality from the base class and adding something to it (*Thanks for the tip, tadman!*):

```
def name
    "#{super}, #{catchphrase}"
end 

def age
    "#{super}, #{catchphrase}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, so do I even need to initialize in the `FrancePresident` class?

Comment: In addition to w0lf's fix, since you have a `name` method, you should not have `attr_accessor :name`.

Comment: @ClydeBrown no, you can leave the `initialize` method out of the class, because it adds nothing to the functionality that already exists in the superclass.

Comment: @Jordan That went through my mind as well. But it's only partially true: the `UnitedStatesPresident` class actually uses the `attr_accessor`s. I see the `name` and `age` methods in `FrancePresident` as "overrides".

Comment: You may want to rewrite those as `"#{super}, #{catchphrase}"`.

Comment: @Jordan, so I can get by without using `attr_accessor :name, :age`?

Comment: @ClydeBrown You'll want to follow w0lf's advice. He has the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the result based on all of your comments. Thanks for all your help!

```
class President
  attr_accessor :name, :age

  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name 
    @age = age
  end 

end

class FrancePresident < President
  def self.citizenship
    "La France"
  end 

 def catchphrase
    "bien sur"
 end

   def name
    "#{@name}, #{catchphrase}"
   end 

   def age
    "#{@age}, #{catchphrase}"
   end 

   def citizenship
     "#{self.class.citizenship}, #{catchphrase}"
   end
end

class UnitedStatesPresident < President
  def self.citizenship
    "The Unites States of America"
  end
end
```